# Why Doesn't This TextMate 2 Bundle Command Set a Codebug Breakpoint?

Tags: textmatebundles, textmate2, codebug

This TextMate 2 bundle command:

```
echo $TM_FILEPATH
echo $TM_LINE_NUMBER
open codebug://send?file="$TM_FILEPATH"&line="$TM_LINE_NUMBER"&op="add"&open="1"
```

generates this echoed output:

```
    /Users/bob/Dropbox/SyncedSites/vhosts/www.br.dev/user/plugins/topicmenu/topicmenu.php
56
```

It launches Codebug, but does not open the referenced file nor set a breakpoint at the specified line.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

With some help over on the #textmate IRC from inifinight, this is what worked:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby18

require "#{ENV['TM_SUPPORT_PATH']}/lib/escape.rb"

`open "codebug://send?file=#{e_url(ENV['TM_FILEPATH'])}&line=#{ENV['TM_LINE_NUMBER']}&op=add&open=1"`
```